# NTPD Pseudo Servers

Tags: gps, timing, ntp, gpsd, gps-time

Good evening!

I'm configuring NTP on an embedded Linux system connected with an U-Blox GPS receiver. I've used NTPD and GPSD.

I would like to know what's the technical difference between:

- PPS Signal provided by the GPSD shared memory SHM, (Pseudo IP Address 127.127.28.1);
- PPS Signal "Stand Alone", but always connected in some way I would like to understand, with GPS (Pseudo IP Address 127.127.22.0)

It is critical for me to understand because I really need an high level synchronization and I would like the right information from the receiver.
Searching all over the web I've found only confused answers to my doubt...

Thanks in advance!

FL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SHM driver is not designed to provide a PPS signal by itself. So maybe your notion here is misguided.

A PPS signal is used for getting a (precise) notion of the 
frequency of the local clock (the one used for measuring external signals), as it just provides a well known timing distance of the "pulses" (1s in this case). Actually pps is a frequency source.

GPSD on the other hand is communicating with some device (could be built into your HW). It then proovides the *time data* read from the GPS source via shared memory to *ntp*. This provisioning of data does not guarantee any timing relation (delay). (E.g. could occur earlier or later within the second due to load or scheduling)

From the perspective of ntp, you will have a true date/time label, but you might not  know exactly **when** the related point in time did occur related to your local clock. (Usually not precisely enough for common *ntp* use cases.) This is where PPS kicks in.

Depending on how the GPS device is being connected to your local machine (parallel, serial, internal bus) you will have some way of getting an interrupt **on the pulse** from the pps signal. (e.g. with serial connection you usually will get a transition on the DCD pin).
The internal processing of the related interrupt will read the local clock and the resulting timing information is then provided for further processing. This information is exactly what the PPS clock discipline is using and providing to ntp. What you need to configure here, is the offset from the triggering of the pulse to reading the local clock. (Pulse usually is assumed to occur "on the second.)

So, in your configuration, it is likely that the "source" of the PPS signal is the same GPSD is using for providing date/time data (your GPS device).
However, the actual *signal*  used for date/time data and pps is different. Date/time will use a data telegram or  some register content read from the GPS device while pps will be a level change on an input pin proveded from this very device.

For details start with the interfacing information from your GPS receiver, especialy any timings stated there. Then look at ntp and figure what driver(s) will allow exploiting such input data for best time quality.

Comment: Think I got it! Thanks a lot!